# Problem with syntax, code works fine in a different area of my project. VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

So I am trying to update a database and a datagridview with a "save" button, I used the part of this code earlier in my program for another function, but here it is giving me a syntax error. Can anyone tell me where? I don't understand where it is.

This part of the code works when I add an employee.

```vb
Private Sub AddEmployee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddEmployee.Click
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, mystring
    Msg = "Do you want to add employee ?"
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2
    Title = "MsgBox Demonstration"
    ' Display message.
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    If Response = vbYes Then
        TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Database13DataSet)
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO dbo.employees (EmpID, LastName, FirstName, AddressHalf, SSN, VehNumb, Certification)  values ('" + EmpID.Text + "' , '" + LastName1.Text + "', '" + FirstName1.Text + "', '" + AddyHalf1.Text + "', '" + SocialNum.Text + "', '" + VehNumb.Text + "', '" + Certification1.Text + "')"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Employee Added")
    Else
        mystring = True
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelled")
    End If
    con.Close()
```

This part of the code is the part that doesn't work. I think it has something to do with my coding trying to update a table but I cannot figure it out.

```vb
    Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
        Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, mystring
        Msg = "Do you want to update employee ?"
        Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2
        Title = "MsgBox Demonstration"
        ' Display message.
        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
        If Response = vbYes Then
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Database13DataSet)
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "Update employees SET (EmpID, LastName, FirstName, AddressHalf, SSN, VehNumb, Certification)  Where ( ModEmpID.Text , ModLastName.Text , ModFirstName.Text,  ModAddy.Text ,  ModSSN.Text , ModVehNum.Text , ModCerts.Text )"
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Employee Added")
            con.Close()
        Else
            mystring = True
            MessageBox.Show("Cancelled")
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Updating()
        Me.EmployeesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database13DataSet.Employees)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `insert into (columns) values (data)` is an actual SQL syntax. `update set (columns) where (data)` is not an SQL syntax, it is something you have invented. You cannot therefore argue that same thing works in the other part of your project. Please refer to the [actual syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) of the `UPDATE` statement, but before that please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683.

Comment: In adition to what @GSerg has said, you will find that string concatenation to build sql statements can be incredibly unreliable and sometimes very difficult to debug.  Learn to use parameters

Comment: @CaiusJard, very true.  Got into the habit now of everytime I see an SQL command string looking for concatenations and not looking at anything else, poor form on my part

Comment: @Hursey right there with you; actually I glanced at the code and must have picked out the "update employee ?" in a string (in the msgbox question constant) and I was like "yes! Woohoo, a VB question where they use parameters and I don't have to deliver the bobby tables lecture!" And then I realized..

Comment: @Gserg, your stackoverflow did not help. I am new at this. But thank you for confusing me even more.

Comment: FYI when there is "an error" it is very helpful if you include the exact text of that error, including the line of code where that happens. It usually gives hints on the real issue, even if *you* cannot decode it yet

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> If Response = vbYes Then
>     TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Database13DataSet)
>     con.Open()
>     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
>     cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO dbo.employees (EmpID, LastName, FirstName, AddressHalf, SSN, VehNumb, Certification)  values ('" + EmpID.Text + "' , '" + LastName1.Text + "', '" + FirstName1.Text + "','" + AddyHalf1.Text + "', '" + SocialNum.Text + "', '" + VehNumb.Text + "', '" + Certification1.Text + "')"
>     cmd.Connection = con
>     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     MessageBox.Show("Employee Added")
> Else
> ```

Nooo.

It doesn't work like that; it was specifically intended *not* to work like that

---

You have tableadapters; nowhere at all, ever, in *any* of **your** code should there be `"INSERT INTO..` or `"UPDATE ..`, select, delete or any other kind of SQL

Let's have a real quick back-to-basics

At some point you've followed some tutorial that probably had you do something that caused a XyzDataSet.xsd file to appear in your project. Inside it there are datatables and tableadapters and the whole thing looks kinda like a database.

It's a local representation of a database; the table adapters download data from the database into the dataset's datatables; you manipulate the data/show the user/change it/add to it/delete from it..
..and when you're done you call upon the tableadapter to push it back to the database.

TableAdapters know how to do all that stuff you've put in your code; you can open the XyzDataSet.Designer.vb file and see it; it has thousands of lines of code intended for pulling and pushing a database

If you reach a point where you think "I don't actually have a facility for... downloading all the employees called smith" then you go to your dataset, you find the employees table adapter, you right click it and you Add Query.. `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name like @name`, you call it FillByName, you finish the wizard, and suddenly your `employeeTableAdapter` has a new method called FillByName that takes a datatable and a string name. You call it like `eta.FillByName(myXyzDataset.Employees, "Smith")` - it does all the databasey bit for you, the command, the parameters, the connection..

You want to add a new employee; again it's dead easy and the tableadapter will save it, you just have to put the new emp into the local datatable:

```
Dim emp = myXyzDataSet.Employees.NewEmployeeRow()

emp.Name = "John Smith"
emp.Age = 23
...

myXyzDataSet.Employees.AddEmployeeRow(emp)
```

There's a shortcut if you know all the values:

```
myXyzDataSet.Employees.AddEmployeeRow("John Smith", 23, ...)
```

Either way your local data cache, the datatable, now contains a new record that needs saving. That's done with:

```
employeeTableAdapter.Update(myXyzDataSet.Employees)
```

The TA will look at the row and see it has been recently added. It will run the INSERT command it has built in - you don't need to do it

If you had edited a row:

```
Dim r = myXyzDataSet.Employees(0) 'first one.. or maybe you'll loop and find John Smith, or use the Find method..

r.Name = "Joe Smith"
```

Then the row knows it has been altered. The tableadapter will know it too, and when you call Update (think of it like Save, it's not just for SQL UPDATE) it will fire the built in UPDATE command and save the name change back to the DB.

Happens similarly for DELETE..

TableAdapters are the devices that pull and push data. If you want to add custom SQLs to your app, add them to the TAs and call the methods. Don't fill your code with direct use of db commands

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify the best. I "the fake programmer" will not be adding or removing or modifying anything in the database. The user will. So me adding any code into the project is not what I am looking to do. I am just learning all of this and it is very confusing.

Comment: I have added them just fine and my code works. It is modifying them that I cannot get to work. It does not update the database. I have no idea how to use a table adapter as I have seen some speaking of.

Comment: I am also confused because the first part of my code works fine, yet you said it was not intended to work like that. It works fine and adds an employee to the datagridview & Database...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out after another hour...

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, mystring
    Msg = "Do you want to update employee ?"
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2
    Title = "MsgBox Demonstration"
    ' Display message.
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    If Response = vbYes Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = Me.ModEmpID.Text
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = Me.ModLastName.Text
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = Me.ModFirstName.Text
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = Me.ModAddy.Text
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = Me.ModSSN.Text
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value = Me.ModVehNum.Text
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value = Me.ModCerts.Text

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand("", con)
            cmd4.CommandText = "update Employees set LastName ='" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "' , FirstName= '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "' , AddressHalf = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "' , SSN = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value & "' , VehNumb = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value & "' , Certification = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value & "'Where EmpID = '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'  "
            con.Open()
            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Employee Updated")

    Else
        mystring = True
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled")
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```